# rewrite rule is ignored

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, rules

I have some problems with rewrite rule. I have 2 scripts, `article.php?url=` and `product.php?ulrprodus=` and I want to setup for them rewrite rules like below:

My Rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ article.php?url=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ produs.php?urlprodus=$1
```

Only one rewrite is functioning `article.php?url=$1`. If I reverse the order also only rewrite will functioning but this time `product.php?urlprodus=$1`.

I need both to be functional.

Comment: The patterns on both rules are the same.  How is Apache supposed to know which rule to use for any given url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^article/([a-z0-9-/]+).html$ article.php?url=$1  [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^produs/([a-z0-9-/]+).html$ produs.php?urlprodus=$1 [NC,L]
```

So rewrite matches are different; now you would be able to make rewrite from say

```
www.domain.tld/article/myRewriteRule.html
```

to

```
www.domain.tld/article.php?url=myRewriteRule
```

In action;

```
$ cat .htaccess 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ article.php?url=$1  [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^produs/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ produs.php?urlprodus=$1 [NC,L]

$ cat article.php 
<?
print_r($_GET);
?>

$ curl -i localhost/article/hello-world.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 11 Nov 2014 12:57:38 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 35
Content-Type: text/html

Array
(
    [url] => hello-world
)
```

Comment: Hi sir,i tried your method and it doesn't work. url is like categorie-1/subcategorie-1.html and urlprodus is like categorie-1/subcategorie-1/produs-subcategorie-1.html .Both of them I extract from the MySQL database.

Comment: I've updated answer with details and checks I made